# Should i pass react hooks as a value to Context Provider?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I need global variable users that is able to filtering out some users. Using react hooks passed as a value leading to rerendering page many times. Which solution is better and why?

```
    export const UsersProvider = props => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({
    isLogged: false
  });

  return (
    <UsersContext.Provider value={[filteredUsers, setFilteredUsers]}>
{props.children}
    </UsersContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

**OR**

```
class UserProvider extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.setUser = () => {
      this.setState(state => {
        return {user: "true"};
      });
      console.log(this.state.user);
    };

    // State also contains the updater function so it will
    // be passed down into the context provider
    this.state = {
      user: false,
      setUser: this.setUser
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <UserContext.Provider value={this.state}>
        {this.props.children}
      </UserContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to add what you need to use in a consumer. Personally I only supply a couple functions/values like this:

```
export const UsersProvider = props => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({
    isLogged: false
  });

  const props = {
    filteredUsers,
    setFilteredUsers
  };

  return (
    <UsersContext.Provider {...props}>
      {props.children}
    </UsersContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

But I'd only add the things you need elsewhere to the props object. I doubt you need everything on your current component's state elsewhere because if you do, you may have an organization problem.